# How to replace/delete a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

how can I replace/delete a part of a string, like this

```
string = '{DDBF1F} this is my string {DEBC1F}'
#{DDBF1F} the code between Parentheses is random, I only know it is made out of 6 characters
```

the output should be

```
this is my string
```

I tried this, I know it doesn't work, but I tried :3

```
string = '{DDBF1F} Hello {DEBC1F}'
string.replace(f'{%s%s%s%s%s%s}', 'abc')
print(string)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `re` library to perform a regex replace, like this:

```
import re

text = '{DDBF1F} Hello {DEBC1F}'
result = re.sub(r"(\s?\{[A-F0-9]{6}\}\s?)", "", text)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the length of the strings within the brackets is fixed, you can use slicing to get the inner substring:

```
>>> string = '{DDBF1F} this is my string {DEBC1F}'
>>> string[8:-8]
' this is my string '
```

(`string[9:-9]` if you want to remove the surrounding spaces)

If hardcoding the indexes feels bad, they can be derived using [str.index](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) (if you can be certain that the string will not contain an embedded '}'):

```
>>> start = string.index('}')
>>> start
7
>>> end = string.index('{', start)
>>> end
27
>>> string[start+1:end]
' this is my string '
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works

`string = '{DDBF1F} this is my string {DEBC1F}'
st=string.split(' ')
new_str=''
for i in st:
    if i.startswith('{') and i.endswith('}'):
        pass
    else:
        new_str=new_str+" "+ i
print(new_str)`